# Maximal bishops per NxN chessboard, how can i find ALL solutions instead of just one

Tags: java, algorithm, chess

I created an algorithm that will place a maximal number of bishops on the NxN chessboard but only works for 1 solution. Is it possible to upgrade this algorithm so it shows me all possible solutions?
The way this algorithm work is by indexing diagonals of the matrix and storing their indexes in HashSet and if the current index is not in the HashSet's the bishop will be placed in that field.

Indexing diagonals:

- LeftToRight = I - J
- RightToLeft = I + J

Code:

```
    public static void maxBishop() {
    HashSet<Integer> leftToRight = new HashSet<>();
    HashSet<Integer> rightToLeft = new HashSet<>();

    int[][] matrix = {
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};


    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            if (!rightToLeft.contains(i + j) && !leftToRight.contains(i - j)) {
                matrix[i][j] = 1;
                rightToLeft.add(i + j);
                leftToRight.add(i - j);
            }
        }
    }

  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HashSet is overkill for this.  Just use a boolean [] since the index is known. E.g for i+j,  rightToLeft[i+j] = true. For the negative, an array still works with a fixed offset of 9, leftToRight[9+i-j] = true.  No more HashSet, or method calls in the main loop.

As for the algorithm in general, you could use recursion.  You've got to consider, what if I don't place the first bishop at 0,0?  Basically, once you've found one solution you need to back out your last placement and check if a bishop would have also fit at the position after that (and repeat).  Once you've exhausted all possibilities for the last position, then back up and try different possibilities for the second last position, etc.  Remember the board state for the maximum bishops placed and discard any board states that have less than your current maximum.

```
public class MaxBishop {
    private static final int DIM = 10;
    private static final int DIM_M_1 = DIM-1;
    private static final int DIM_SQ = DIM*DIM;
    static boolean[] leftToRight = new boolean[2*DIM];
    static boolean[] rightToLeft = new boolean[2*DIM];

    static boolean[] matrix = new boolean[DIM_SQ];

    static int maxBishops = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        maxBishop(0,0);
    }

    public static void maxBishop(int start, int numPlaced) {
        for (int p = start; p < DIM_SQ; p++) {
            int i = p / DIM;
            int j = p - i * DIM;
            if (!rightToLeft[i + j] && !leftToRight[DIM_M_1 + i - j]) {
                place(i,j);
                maxBishop(p+1, numPlaced+1);
                remove(i,j);
            }
        }
        if (numPlaced >= maxBishops) {
            maxBishops = numPlaced;
            printBoard(matrix, numPlaced);
        }
    }

    static void place(int i, int j) {
        matrix[i*DIM+j] = true;
        rightToLeft[i + j] = true;
        leftToRight[DIM_M_1 + i - j] = true;
    }

    static void remove(int i, int j) {
        matrix[i*DIM+j] = false;
        rightToLeft[i + j] = false;
        leftToRight[DIM_M_1 + i - j] = false;
    }
    
    static void printBoard(boolean[] matrix, int bishops) {
        System.out.println("\n"+bishops+" bishops:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                System.out.print(matrix[i*DIM+j] ? 'B' : '.');
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Note you would have to account for mirror images and rotated versions of solutions already found.